# Both 404 and 200 status on same page

Tags: c#

If i "Fiddle" my website i see that a few of my pages present with a 404 error status and then directly afterwards it presents with a 200 status. 
The page loads correctly with out ever displaying the "page cannot be found" page.

Example of fiddler result set.

**Result    Protocol URL

404 HTTP    Test/Admin/undefined

200 HTTP    Test/Admin/Testpage.aspx**

Can anyone please tell me why this would be??
This also does not always happen. On first load of the page the status is 200. But if i click a button or redirect to the page again then i end up with the above example.

Comment: `undefined` hints at a javascript issue. unless you post the code then there is no way any of us can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there is wrong expectation in your javascript code. Are you concatenating there the url with some value calculated in javascript? If the value will not be available then it may result in such broken url.

Comment: In this case i am not concatenating anything to the URL. i am using a master page though that has javascript functions. But i am only reloading the page. I do register Jquery but only after my page has loaded. If it was the Jquery i would receive this error on all my pages instead of only this one.

Comment: Please try to use Firebug or Developer tools to debug your code. It will tell you what is not initialized there.